# Publishing Of .cs File

Tags: c#, asp.net

Recently I  added a test.cs file in a folder other than app_Code (let us say Settings) in a .net website project. When I published the webapp, no dll got created in the bin folder. Moreover the settings folder remained empty too. But when I moved the settings folder in app_code folder and re-published the app, then I got a dll in published app.

Can any one tell me why is this happening and what happens to .cs files in both of the above cases?

Thanks And Regards

Comment: Why are you wanting to publish your source code ?

Comment: I cant deliver code to client,

Comment: Are you using a Web Site or a Web Application project type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recognized my mistake, i was trying to open the project as website, When i opened it as project and then complied it the changes in my .cs files got reflected